# Fixed size arrays in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell, data-kinds

I was trying to write a library for linear algebra operations in Haskell. In order to be able to define safe operations for matrices and vectors I wanted to encode their dimensions in their types. After some research I found that using DataKinds one is able to do that, similar to the way it's done [here](https://blog.jle.im/entry/fixed-length-vector-types-in-haskell.html). For example:

```
data Vector (n :: Nat) a

dot :: Num a => Vector n a -> Vector n a -> a
```

In the aforementioned article, as well as in some libraries, the size of the vectors is a phantom type and the vector type itself is a wrapper around an Array. In trying to figure out if there is a array type with its size at the type-level in the standard library I started wondering about the underlying representation of arrays. From what I could gather form [this commentary](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/rts/storage/heap-objects) on GHC memory layout, arrays need to store their size on the heap so a 3-dimensional vector would need to take up 1 more word than necessary. Of course we could use the following definition:

```
data Vector3 a = Vector3 a a a
```

which might be fine if we only care about 3D geometry, but it doesn't allow for vectors of arbitrary size and also it makes indexing awkward.

So, my question is this. Wouldn't it be useful and a potential memory optimization to have an array type with statically known size in the standard library? As far, as I understand the only thing that it would need is a different info table, which would store the size, instead of it being stored for at each heap object. Also, the compiler could choose between Array and SmallArray automatically.

Comment: “Wouldn't it be useful and a potential memory optimization” – perhaps. However many applications have so large arrays that the overhead of storing the size at runtime is negligible, whereas the applications dealing with only 2D or 3D tend to have those hard-coded. — IMO a good linear algebra library should generally not have dimensions visible _at all_, neither at compile- nor runtime. Instead, it should be dealing with abstract [vector spaces](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space). My attempt at such a library is https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Even in the case of abstract vector spaces one would eventually need to define datatypes for specific vector spaces. As far as I can see neither of the libraries you mention does that, but rather they provide a general interface (via typeclasses mostly). So I think these two aspects are independent. In any case, many libraries deal with finite dimensional spaces specifically. Of course for large matrices this memory overhead is not an issue, but for an array of 2D vectors,  the vertices of a 2D shape for example, it would be.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that you don't write your code to rely on any of these specific vector space datatypes, but instead leave it abstract over the type classes. Then you get to instantiate the same code for both e.g. [`V2 Double`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.21.8/docs/Linear-V2.html) (which does not store any size at runtime), or a type for big vectors that does store the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wouldn't it be useful and a potential memory optimization to have an array type with statically known size in the standard library?

Sure. I suspect if you wrote up your use case carefully and implemented this, GHC HQ would accept a patch. You might want to do the writeup first and double-check that they're into it to avoid wasting time on a patch they won't accept, though; I certainly don't speak for them.

> Also, the compiler could choose between Array and SmallArray automatically.

I'm not an expert here, but I kinda doubt this. Usually supporting polymorphism means you need a uniform representation.

Comment: Well, I don't think I have the technical knowledge to implement this myself, but maybe I can make a feature request. Thank you for your answer.